# Docusign Nuget package github

Tags: docusignapi

Does the github nuget package of Docusign support TLS 1.2 ? With the latest move to TLS 1.2 on docusign, can anyone confirm that the binaries on github support TLS 1.2 automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release candidate on nuget supports TLS 1.2. It also includes a new getUserInfo method. getUserInfo must be used to determine the user's information including base url when OAuth authentication is used.

Comment: I am using 2.1.7 , I have received notification from manamgement today that Docusign will move to TLS 1.2 today.  
I am concerned that my production application which uses Envelopes API , may fail from tmrw.

Comment: DocuSIgn has delayed the end of life for TLS 1.0 for API applications and customers' Connect servers / listeners.

Comment: What is the new date for EOL TLS 1 set by docusign

Comment: Hasn't been set yet. There will be a request process to have your DocuSign account exempted from the no-TLS 1.0 update. Contact your DocuSign technical rep.